# Why can't I get this page using wget in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, browser, ubuntu, wget

http://121.199.111.177

I access this URL using win7(IE8), it's ok, I can get the page.

But if I using wget, or under Ubuntu desktop with Chrome or Firefox, I can't get any things.

Like this:

```
root@ubuntu:~# wget 121.199.111.177
--07:57:52--  http://121.199.111.177/
            => `index.html.1'
Connecting to 121.199.111.177:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

I tried using user-agent, but still not work:

```
root@ubuntu:~# wget --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)" http://121.199.111.177/
--08:08:04--  http://121.199.111.177/
           => `index.html.1'
Connecting to 121.199.111.177:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

Why? How can I get this page use wget?

Comment: on linux firefox 3.5 it does not work also

Comment: Does it work in Firefox on Windows?

Comment: mpapis ,yes, this site like only for windows,it's weird

Comment: Can you show us the contents you see on windows? In chromium on ubuntu i get something but it shows the same error 500 that wget sees.

Comment: robert ,they can work on windows, (firefox+win7,chrome+win7...),but all linux will be not work

Comment: marcog,the page title is"IIS 7.5 详细错误 - 500.19 - Internal Server Error", i want using wget get this page(500 page),but only windows can see it

Comment: @Zenofo That's the same that I get on chromium on ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error code 500 is an internal server error. Wget reads this error code in the headers and doesn't even bother getting the contents. So there's a problem with the server that needs to be fixed.

```
$ wget -S http://121.199.111.177/
--2010-12-05 02:18:32--  http://121.199.111.177/
Connecting to 121.199.111.177:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
  Cache-Control: private
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
  Date: Sun, 05 Dec 2010 00:19:02 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Length: 4722
2010-12-05 02:18:49 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

Some telnet debugging agrees with the above:

```
$ telnet 121.199.111.177 80
Trying 121.199.111.177...
Connected to 121.199.111.177.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
Date: Sun, 05 Dec 2010 00:36:02 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 4722

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 7.5 详细错误 - 500.19 - Internal Server Error</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: @Zenofo That also returns a 500, with the same contents.

Comment: @Zenofo You are getting the exact same thing in IE. There's an error on the server side. Nothing you can do on the client side will fix this.