# Wget Doesn't Retry after Connection Reset by Peer

Tags: linux, wget, gnu, download

I often use `wget` to download large (>100GB) files. Often, it works fine, but I also often run into connection issues like this:

```
...
50449750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29% 1.31M 1h44m
50449800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29% 12.8M 1h44m
50449850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29% 1.27M 1h44m
50449900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29% 3.90M 1h44m
50449950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29% 10.5M 1h44m
50450000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29% 11.8M 1h44m
50450050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29% 1.35M 1h44m
50450100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29% 1.34M 1h44m
50450150K                                                        29%  928G=44m44s

2018-08-16 11:48:55 (18.4 MB/s) - Read error at byte 51660954098/172689731772 (Connection reset by peer).
```

I'm starting the download with

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O /path/to/out.txt -c "https://XXX.s3.amazonaws.com/XXX"
```

**I understand that connection issues may happen, but I thought that `wget` would try again to download the file if they do? Why is that not happening here?**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356603/why-cant-i-get-this-page-using-wget-in-ubuntu), for example, shows output from `wget` retrying after a `Connection reset by peer` error.

---

Full context: I'm actually running this command from a Python script like this

```
            shouldContinue = "-c"
            wget = 'wget --no-check-certificate -O {outputPath} {shouldContinue} "{url}"'.format(
                    outputPath=outputPath,
                    shouldContinue=shouldContinue,
                    url=url
            )

            proc = subprocess.Popen(wget, shell=True)
            proc.wait()
```

---

```
$ wget --version | head -1
GNU Wget 1.14 built on linux-gnu
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Is it possible that it reached the default retry limit of 20 attempts? You can use the `--tries` option to increase the number of attempts. See https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options

Comment: @Barmar Should I move this? I'm happy to do so, but this is in fact a programing question, about writing code for use in a professional setting.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think so. There's no evidence of `wget` opening another connection in the output.

Comment: If the question is about what options to use to make `wget` do automatic retries, it's not a programming question. If it's about writing your own code that does the retries, then it's a programming question. But in that case you need to post your attempted code and explain the problem you're having with it.

Comment: The `-c` option should make it try to restart from where it left off, if the output file already exists and the server supports that option.

Comment: Make sure your version of `wget` is up-to-date.

Comment: @Barmar I wouldn't say it's about finding what options to use make `wget` do automatic retries; my understanding is that `wget` does this by default. I guess it is then about writing my own code that does the retries (though again, my understanding is that `wget` does this by default so I would think just `wget $url` would be enough). My attempted code and the problem I'm having with it are here—is there something specific you think I should add?

Comment: Your version of wget is 6 years old, but AFAICT it should still have automatic retries. I can't understand why it doesn't do it.

Comment: @Barmar I've updated to v1.14 with the same result

Comment: The current version is v1.19.5 v1.14 was released 6 years ago in 2012

Comment: Please add the "-d --progress none" parameters and share the output from when the issue happens. It looks like the number of retries is either exceeded or set to 0.